# Shopify Event for Product Update is missing

Tags: shopify

The events API doc says that the **Product update** events will be recorded if a product info is updated. But I only see **product create** event in the list of events. I don't see any **product update** events. What could be the reason ? Is it a bug in Shopify API ?

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/event#products

Answer (score 0):

Right from the API docs you pointed to:

```
update  product_title was updated.  The product was updated.
```

Not sure how you read that is missing, but it is clearly there.

Comment: I am not saying the doc is missing. Actually it is there in the doc but missing when you test it.

Comment: I see. You are right. Following the Shopify example does not result in an update Event.

Comment: Listen to the update webhook... filter that... for what you need?

Comment: The author info which I need is not there in webhook data being received. That is why I was trying to get it from events.

Comment: I imagine Shopify does not publish updates to Events queue for good reason. Would be a lot of pollution in the event stream. I don't even see the Shopify admin updated that. So you are out of luck it seems. Why do you care who updates a product anyway?

Comment: I need it to know who changed a product. Why they mention that in their doc if that is not possible ? Looks strange !